# How can I generate only a single PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Below is my Code I am generating Password Protected pdf from ItextSharp.

Actually two pdf are getting generating and saving.

But i want only file to be saved.

If I use same for input and output i am getting error.

Truly appreciate your help.

```
Letter1 mydoc = new Letter1();
mydoc.GenerateLetter();  
string WorkingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string InputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "Testing1.pdf");
FileStream f = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Create);
f.Write(mydoc.DocumentBytes, 0, mydoc.DocumentBytes.Length);
f.Close();
string OutputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "TestingOut1.pdf");
using (Stream input = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, "abc123", "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just delete the temporary input file `Testing1.pdf` once the output file is done?

Comment: I spent more time formatting/fixing your question than I normally would spend answering a question. Putting some effort into the question is somewhat required on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to instantiate a separate stream to read the PDF you want to encrypt. Use the [PdfReader overloaded constructor that accepts a file path](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#PdfReader%28java.lang.String%29). Something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(InputFile);
using (Stream output = new FileStream(
    OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None
))
{
  PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(
    reader, output, true, "abc123", "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS
  );    
}
```

Comment: That's true, but he still ends up with a second file which he wants to avoid.

Comment: ?!?!? `InputFile` to me means **existing** file, even though the code snippet uses `FileMode.Create`. The second comment on the question mentions the code snippet was heavily modified by someone else, so it's anyone's guess whether or not the OP is using an existing PDF **or** is creating the PDF from scratch. And you _should_ know that **neither** a temporary file **nor** a `MemoryStream` is necessary for **either** case...

Comment: Hi all, I truly appreciate ur Suggestions. All above Comments works fine for me. Now the Problem is Its directly Getting saved to MyDocuments. I am using MVC3 and I want user to save to his own path by opening a dialogue with Password Potected.Can u giys please Help me on this.

Comment: @kuujinbo, according to the OP's code, `InputFile` is a byte array created from a 3rd party that he's persisting to disk, then read with a `PdfReader` and written back to disk. He wants to avoid the double files and only store the encrypted one. That's why a `MemoryStream` to read the raw bytes would solve this problem. The edits to the original post were for grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a MemoryStream

Untested code (written in browser:)

```
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
{
    m.Write(mydoc.DocumentBytes, 0, mydoc.DocumentBytes.Length);
    m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Origin);

    string OutputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "TestingOut1.pdf");
    using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(m);
        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, "abc123", "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
    }
}
```